# Latex with fncychap

Tags: fncychap

I am using the fncychap package to format my document with the Rejne option.  However, the boxes' size differ when using the commands chapter* and chapter.  The box is slightly wider with the chapter option (see picture below).  Does anyone know how to correct this so that they have the same length ?

[image: Text]

These were generated by the following code.

```
\documentclass{book} 

\usepackage[Rejne]{fncychap} 
\usepackage[nonefgrulers]{fgruler}

\begin{document}

    \chapter*{Star}
        \vspace*{-34mm}\ruler{rightdown}{12.3cm}

    \chapter{No star}
        \vspace*{-19mm}\ruler{rightdown}{12.3cm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... Can you show your actual requirement by posting an image?

Comment: The requirement would be that both boxes be of the same length.  In the image above the first box is 123mm wide and the second one is 120mm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code does the trick:

```
\makeatletter
 \renewcommand{\DOTIS}[1]{%
    \setlength{\py}{\fboxrule}
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\RW}
    \setlength{\mylen}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\mylen}{-2\RW}
    \addtolength{\mylen}{-2\fboxsep} %%%%
    \fbox{\parbox{\mylen}{\vskip 2\baselineskip\CTV\FmTi{#1}\par\nobreak\vskip \baselineskip}} 
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{\py}
    \vskip 60\p@
    }
 \makeatother
```